# how can i install hangul_utils? (subprocess-exited-with-error)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to install hangul_utils many times.
but It comes up as below.

```
Collecting hangul_utils
  Downloading hangul_utils-0.4.5-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from hangul_utils) (4.66.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from hangul_utils) (1.16.0)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of hangul-utils to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Downloading hangul_utils-0.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Downloading hangul_utils-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Downloading hangul_utils-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Downloading hangul_utils-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Downloading hangul_utils-0.4-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Downloading hangul-utils-0.3.0.tar.gz (4.3 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

i tried to change python version from 3.12 to 3.9
and i installed mecab but i fail to start mecab succescfully.
i don't know what i have to do.
please help me

Comment: What OS are you running? Did you follow the steps here https://github.com/kaniblu/hangul-utils#getting-started

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.